# Laravel eloquent model model attribute casting (Which attribute types should I cast?)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am not sure I fully understand Laravel Eloquent attribute casting. According to documentation, (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting), these are the supported types:

integer, real, float, double, decimal:, string, boolean, object, array, collection, date, datetime, timestamp, encrypted, encrypted:object, encrypted:array, and encrypted:collection

So far, I've only used date casting on my models (when the fields were stored as timestamps in the db), like this:

```
protected $dates = [
    'modified_at', 'published_at'
];
```

I also understand the need for attribute casting to boolean when the values are stored as integers (0 or sth else).

But what about other attribute types (integers, for example), should I always do attribute casting? Or just when the field in the database is of a different type? What are the use cases or what is the best practice with other attributes?

(I can't, for example, imagine creating a string field in migrations, then saving some number inside it as string and then casting it back into an integer on the model?)

Comment: The idea of casts is to convert the attribute on Set or Get depending on the type and what you want to achive.. There is option to make and custom casts ..
 https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, attributes will be casted to the type of column defined in the table. So, if your column is an integer, then it will be casted as `int`.

But, what happens if you want to modify this behavior for specific fields? That's when attribute casting enters the scene.

For example, imagine we have in a table called `projects` a column named `config` of type `json` in which we can store additional configuration elements for each project.

In my case, it'd be useful to be able to handle this data as an `array`. So, instead of receiving a `string` or `object`, we can just deal with a simple `array`. To do this, we just:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    // ...

    protected $casts = [
        'config' => 'array',
    ];

    // ...
}
```

This way, whenever we use Eloquent to fetch projects from the database, each record will have that property as an `array`. And also, it will be converted back to `json` when trying to store/update records.

Related to the case you specified (saving element as a `string` but then retrieve it as an `integer`) is totally possible of course. You'll need to set both the accessor and the mutator for that field. For an attribute named `number`:

```
/**
 * This will be called when fetching the element.
 */
public function getNumberAttribute($value)
{
    return (int)$value;
}

/**
 * This will be called when storing/updating the element.
 */
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['number'] = (string)$value;
}
```

Now, **a reason to ever need to make this?** Well, you could be dealing with a database not properly well designed, or with a production database that is being used by multiple systems and changes in the db are hard to accomplish. In those cases you could make use of this kind of value manipulation to work as you want in your app.

Comment: thanks, Kenny, that clears it up...cast when need/want to, but not all the time

Comment: Clear and very knowledgeable answer. Thank you Kenny!

Comment: it was very helpful thank you for taking from your time to explore this i understanded it well from you